# How to design the database schema for this activity planner

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Hi I am new to database design and would like help designing the schema for activity planner for patients with depression. (this is a little project I am working on to build my skills).

What I am thinking right now is to have a table for user information, table for what the user plans to do the next day (the first coloumn), and another table for the patient to fill out at the end of the day (the rows, but with additional time input such as "Early morning" or "Night"

But with this current schema, when the patient inputs their activities at the end of the day, the app will need to make 6 calls (bc of the 6 different times periods such as afternoon, evening, etc)

Any help would he appreciated!

```
-- ************************************** "user"

CREATE TABLE "user"
(
 "id"        uuid NOT NULL,
 "email"     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 "lastName"  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 "firstName" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "PK_user" PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ),
);

-- ************************************** "Plan"
CREATE TABLE "Plan"
(
 "id"             uuid NOT NULL,
 "date"           date NOT NULL,
 "earlyMorning"   text NOT NULL,
 "lateMorning"    text NOT NULL,
 "earlyAfternoon" text NOT NULL,
 "evening"        text NOT NULL,
 "night"          text NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "PK_Plan" PRIMARY KEY ( "id", "date" )
);

-- ************************************** "Actual"

CREATE TABLE "Actual"
(
 "id"          uuid NOT NULL,
 "date"        date NOT NULL,
 "time"        text NOT NULL,
 "actuallyDid" text NOT NULL,
 "mood"        smallint NOT NULL,
 "triggers"    text NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "PK_Actual" PRIMARY KEY ( "id", "date" )
);
```

[image: Activity Planner from WebMD]

(Picture from webmd)

Comment: I'd recommend you to study DB normalization. At first sight: Plan table must be (id - date - time period-planned), Actual must contain a reference to Plan.

Comment: Hey @Akina - can you please recommend any books for DB normalization? Thanks!